# При конвертации объекта в json, а затем обратно теряется информация о файле

Tags: javascript, файлы, объекты

Проблема состоит в том, что нужно узнать информацию о том, сколько весит файл, и когда был редактирован в последний раз, но при использовании данного кода =>=>=>

```js
onDropFiles(files) {
  console.log(files) // до конвертации всё нормально
  let objFile = JSON.stringify(files)
  console.log(objFile);
  console.log(JSON.parse(objFile)); //здесь же получаю только лишь 2 значения

},
```

остаётся только то, что выделено жирным в консоли, в чём может быть ошибка?

**Скрин до**
[image: Скрин до]

**Скрин после**
[image: Скрин после]

Comment: JSON.stringify и JSON.parse - Вам самим не кажется что это костыль? решение гораздо проще

Comment: Кажется, очень даже сильно. Есть такое чувство, что копаю совсем не туда

Comment: Эти функции больше подходят для работы с json файлами, использование их в других случаях очень часто не оправдано, я повидал много всякого, но это не надежный способ извлечения данных, что и показывает Ваш личный опыт.

Comment: JSON умеет работать только с примитивными типами и простыми объектами и массивами. Всё остальное либоьвыкидывает исключение либо по тихому превращается в пустой объект.

Comment: Но самый главный вопрос: а зачем вы вообще хотите запихать файл в JSON. stringify?

Comment: Где-то прочитал о том, что для отправки в `form data` через axios необходимо конвертировать содержимое объекта в json, потому как до конвертации на сервере я получал переменную $_POST['files'] с таким и только таким значением `[object File]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начну с того почему теряется информация, скорее всего по причине того что в объекте файл определена функция которая выбирает именно эти 2 поля для сериализации в строку наверно по причине того что данные изначально строки в отличие от остальных (числа, даты)

Вот пример как это может происходить:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, date){
    this.name = name
    this.date = date
  }
}

p = new Person('JOHN', new Date())
console.log(JSON.stringify(p)); // будет и имя и дата

p.toJSON = function(){ return {"name": this.name}} // <------
console.log(JSON.stringify(p)); // тут не будет даты
```

Извлечение данных из объектов можно делать гораздо более удобным способом, разумеется с дополнительными проверками. Например файл может быть один, или несколько, тогда это либо объект либо массив объектов. Как только мы определились с тем что же мы получили на входе, нам нужно извлечь к примеру дату и размер из файла:

```
const {lastModifiedDate, size} = file // files[0]
```

Таким образом в случае с одним файлом можно получить нужную информацию в константы. Если файлов будет много то делаем то же самое но в цикле, сохраняя в массив.